# UWP Contact picker picks only names' fields of contacts in Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Using the contact picker in a UWP app to pick a contact as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/selecting-contacts) works on PC correctly, while on mobile device it can only return the names fields (Name, FirstName, LastName, FullName) but nothing else such as Adresses, Phones, Emails ... etc.

```
var contactPicker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();
Contact contact = await contactPicker.PickContactAsync();
if (contact != null)
    {
    string xx = "";

        if (contact.Addresses.Count > 0) 
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Addresses[0].Country)) xx+="Country: "+ contact.Addresses[0].Country+"\n";
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Addresses[0].Description)) xx+="Description: "+ contact.Addresses[0].Description+"\n";
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Addresses[0].Locality)) xx+="Locality: "+ contact.Addresses[0].Locality+"\n";
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Addresses[0].PostalCode)) xx+="PostalCode: "+ contact.Addresses[0].PostalCode+"\n";
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Addresses[0].Region)) xx+="Region: "+ contact.Addresses[0].Region+"\n";
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Addresses[0].StreetAddress)) xx+="StreetAddress: "+ contact.Addresses[0].StreetAddress+"\n";
            }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.DisplayName)) xx+="DisplayName: "+ contact.Addresses[0].DisplayName+"\n";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.DisplayNameOverride)) xx+="DisplayNameOverride: "+ contact.Addresses[0].DisplayNameOverride+"\n";
        if (contact.Emails.Count > 0)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Emails[0].Address)) xx+="Email: "+ contact.Addresses[0].Address+"\n";
            }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.FirstName)) xx+="FirstName: "+ contact.Addresses[0].FirstName+"\n";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.FullName)) xx+="FullName: "+ contact.Addresses[0].FullName+"\n";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.LastName)) xx+="LastName: "+ contact.Addresses[0].LastName+"\n";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.MiddleName)) xx+="MiddleName: "+ contact.Addresses[0].MiddleName+"\n";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Name)) xx+="Name: "+ contact.Addresses[0].Name+"\n";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Nickname)) xx+="Nickname: "+ contact.Addresses[0].Nickname+"\n";
        if (contact.Phones.Count > 0)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Phones[0].Number)) xx+="Phone: "+ contact.Addresses[0].Number+"\n";
            }

        textBlock.Text = xx;
    }
```

works on PC correctly and shows the data of the picked contact. But when running it on a mobile device running Win 10 Mobile, it shows only the names of the picked contact.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code in [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/selecting-contacts), and the software can display the contact name, email address, phone number and other information.

By comparing with your code, I found that you may lack the definition of `DesiredFieldsWithContactFieldType`.

Try adding these to your code:

```cs
ContactPicker contactPicker = new ContactPicker();

contactPicker.DesiredFieldsWithContactFieldType.Add(ContactFieldType.Email);
contactPicker.DesiredFieldsWithContactFieldType.Add(ContactFieldType.Address);
contactPicker.DesiredFieldsWithContactFieldType.Add(ContactFieldType.PhoneNumber);

Contact contact = await contactPicker.PickContactAsync();
```

Once added, ContactPicker will pick the contacts that contain these fields in order to get the information you want.

Best regards.

Comment: It worked partially better. After adding them, it shows now the details of the selected contact (emails, addresses and phone numbers) so that the user should select one of them. Thus, the user can select the email, the address or the phone number, but not many of them! i.e. if the contact has a phone number and an email address, the user can select **either** the phone number **or** the email address!!

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear about what you mean. `contactPicker.PickContactAsync()` could get all the information of the contact, including all the calls, all the email addresses. You can decide which display and which ones are not displayed. You need to filter the obtained `IList<ContactEmail>` or `IList<ContactPhone>`. Are you experiencing problems during the screening process?